# Data from web issue

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I have a macro that I run that uses 4 separate static urls that have html links within. As of Saturday 8/5 I am no longer able to use my macro because when I log into my password protected website on IE it no longer remembers my password in the Excel macro when it uses the data from website procedure. It does remember my password in Chrome and Firefox, but from what I understand IE is the only browser that Excel will use. Does anyone have a work-around or know why IE would suddenly stop carrying over login information to Excel when it would before?

In IE internet options I have checked:

Content>Auto Compelete settings> Username and passwords on forms

Comment: Test this macro on another computer. Same result?

Comment: Yes, I am led to believe that excel will only use IE as a broswer. Do you know if this is true?(for the "From web")